Julia docstring gets replaced
I make the following module:
module Foo

export Bar

"""
    Bar

Struct bar docstring.

"""
struct Bar
    n::Int

    @doc """
        Bar(n::Int)

    Constructor docstring.

    """
    function Bar(n::Int)
        return new(n)
    end
end

end

When I ask for the documentation of Bar in the REPL, I get both the docstring for the struct as well as that for the constructor.
Now, if I overload function call by adding:
"""
    (b::Bar)(x::Int)

Do something.

"""
function (b::Bar)(x::Int)
    return b.n + x
end

then when I do using Foo I get a warning: Replacing docs for Foo.Bar :: Tuple{Int64} in module Foo. The docstring for the constructor is then replaced by the docstring for the function call operator.
How can I keep both docstrings?

Where do you add the other method Bar? Help of Bar is all 3 docstrings if second Bar method was added outside of module Foo in the Main module for Julia v1.10.4.

module Foo

export Bar

"""
    Bar

Struct bar docstring.

"""
struct Bar
    n::Int

    @doc """
        Bar(n::Int)

    Constructor docstring.

    """
    function Bar(n::Int)
        return new(n)
    end
end

end

using Main.Foo

"""
    (b::Bar)(x::Int)

Do something.

"""
function (b::Bar)(x::Int)
    return b.n + x
end

Help of Bar will provide all doc strings already in Julia v1.10.4:
help?> Bar
search: Bar baremodule SubArray GlobalRef BitArray clipboard backtrace BitMatrix catch_backtrace AbstractRange AbstractArray

  (b::Bar)(x::Int)

  Do something.

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  Bar(n::Int)

  Constructor docstring.

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  Bar

  Struct bar docstring.


Thanks for the response.  I make the Foo module in its own file (Foo.jl) and the function call method is defined there as well.  I don't want to define it outside of Foo.  I still get the same problem.  Is there a work around?

Then you have the same method twice so that the first gets replaced by the second resulting in just one docstring. However, you can do multiple Constructors with different arguments, e.g. Bar(n::Int32)
